# My male dog is aggressive to his sister

Tags: dogs, behavior, aggression

My dogs usually fight when there’s food around but only growl at each other never bite each other. But recently my male dog keeps randomly biting/ attacking her. He does this maybe once everyother day. I know it hurts her because she cries when he attacks her. I don’t know what to do about it or what causes him to do it

Comment: Has your dog been fixed? How old are they?

Comment: You need to elaborate more. There are a million different reasons why this could occur. What is their behaviour like before a fight happens? Is there a toy around, or food? What is their behaviour like before and after? What are they doing in the lead up to it? Is there any potential pain or illnesses in one? etc